# Fetch API POST request response returns empty text

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I am trying to get the response of a post request I'm sending via fetch() but the result returns an empty text.

JS:

```
async getTotalCompletionTimes()
{
    var res = await fetch("repository/maps.php?method=getcompletiontimes&map="+this.getName(), {method: 'POST'});
    const result = await res.text();
    return result;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
require_once("user.php");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
<some code>
else if(isset($_POST["method"]) && $_POST["method"] == "getcompletiontimes" && isset($_POST["map"]))
{
    $times = 0;
    $users = glob('../users/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($users as $u)
    {
        if(!file_exists($u."/maps.json")) continue;
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($u."/maps.json"), true);
        foreach($json as $map => $v)
        {
            if($map == $_POST["map"])
            {
                $times += $v;
            }
        }
    }
    echo $times;
}
<some other code>
?>
```

I tested the php response with curl in cmd: curl -X POST localhost/game/repository/maps.php -d "method=getcompletiontimes&map=map_1" and it returned "2" as a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curl request to the server is a `HTTP POST` request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type and the data is transmitted similar to how browsers submit an HTML form.
This request data contains `'method'` and `'map'` parameters.

However, in `fetch` implementation `'method'` and `'map'` parameters are sent as URL query parameters. This way they are not available in the `$_POST` global array but `$_GET` global array.

You can have `'method'` and `'map'` parameters sent to the server in a similar way as the `curl` one by setting the [body option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body) of the `fetch` initialization data to contain form data containing both parameters.

```
async getTotalCompletionTimes()
{
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("method", "getcompletiontimes");
    fd.append("map", this.getName());
    const res = await fetch(
      "repository/maps.php",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: fd
      });
    const result = await res.text();
    return result;
}
```